# android: how to get memory usage (ram) of a given PID programically

Tags: android

i want to log ram usage of a given application at a given time rate. i wrote the code to get the full memory value used but do not know how to get the memory usage of a given PID.

please help me out

this is the code i used to get the memory

```
 ActivityManager localActivityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService("activity");
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo localMemoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    localActivityManager.getMemoryInfo(localMemoryInfo);
    Log.i("",String.valueOf(localMemoryInfo.availMem));
```

i think i can get it using public MemoryInfo[] getProcessMemoryInfo (int[] pids), but do not know how to code for it since im a android beginer

Answer (score 2):

```
ActivityManager localActivityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); // use Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE not the literal "activity"
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procsInfo = localActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

int[] pids = new int[procsInfo.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < procsInfo.size(); i++) {
    ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = procsInfo.get(i);
    pids[i] = info.pid;
}

Debug.MemoryInfo[] procsMemInfo = localActivityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(pids);
// now walk the procsMemInfo array
```

If you schedule a recurring timer to periodically re-query for running pids and query for  memory info you can use timestamps to compute the memory usage over time.

Comment: ohh wow.... first, thank you for helping me out... but when i add this "Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token" if i change this getProcessMemoryInfo gives an error. if you dont mind please can u put the full code for me, just to log the data. ill put it to a list view and do the other things. thnk u