# Get the RAM usage of a process by using its pid android

Tags: android, process, ram, process-management

Is there a way to find out the RAM that every single process is using. I've find out all the pid and total ram usage by all processes. Now I want to find amount of RAM every single process using. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/15828372/603270 ?

Comment: Really thanks for helping :) but i've tried this before. It didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work". I just tried it and it works just fine. Post your code or explain what isn't working.